# Error with getting ForeignKey object from the object it is assigned under

Tags: django

I have two models in my models.py, Question and Choice. Since ForeignKey was used to link Choice as a child of Question, I assumed I could do the same for the built-in user object and the question object. I made a question object and linked it with the user I made, and all worked well until I tried to get the user using "question_object.author" (I named the ForeignKey "author" under the question object). So do I need to link the user and question object another way? or am I just trying to get the user object the wrong way? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Error:
" ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'sheepposu' " sheepposu is name of my user.
The error comes from when I attempted to get the user model from the question model via question_object.author.

This is what it looks like atm. Some of the import are unused but I plan on using them in the future.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Question, Choice
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

User = get_user_model()

def index(request):
    question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10]
    context = {"question_list": question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/questions.html', context)

def get_question_context(question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    context = {
        'question': question,
        'title': 'Poll Question %s: %s' %(question_id, question.question_text)
    }
    return context

def detail(request, question_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context = get_question_context(question_id)
        return render(request, 'polls/question-details.html', context)
    else:
        error_message = "Login/register to vote on questions"
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question_id, error_message)))

def results(request, question_id):
    context = get_question_context(question_id)
    context.update({'percentageDict': {}, 'choices': context['question'].choice_set.all().order_by('-votes')})
    voteList = []
    for choice in context['choices']:
        voteList.append(choice.votes)
    for choice in context['choices']:
        choice.percentage = round((choice.votes/sum(voteList))*100)
        choice.save()
    return render(request, 'polls/question-results.html', context)


def vote(request, question_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        try:
            choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
            context = get_question_context(question_id)
            context.update({'error_message': 'You didn\'t select a choice'})
            return render(request, 'polls/question-details.html', context)
        else:
            choice.votes += 1
            choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question_id,)))
    else:
        error_message = "Login/register to vote on questions"
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question_id, error_message)))
```

For some reason now I cannot copy the output from the command prompt, so the error is "django.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"
This happens whenever I tried to assign a user to the author slot.

Comment: Please, add an error description. What happened, when you "tried to get the user using "question_object.author" "

Comment: please show your `views.py`

Comment: Can you clarify where is the place where you are trying to " get the user model from the question model via question_object.author."? I see no such place in your views.py. What is the file mentioned in the traceback of an error?

Comment: The index function is where I was trying to grab the user object, or rather in the html that index renders. I removed it from my code temporarily in order to go on building other parts since it was only to display some text of who wrote the question.

Comment: Then it possibly the place in your HTML file where you are trying to display the information about the user and passing username instead of id. Thу exact string of a file should be visible in the error traceback.

Comment: The line of code in the html file that causes an error is "{{ question.author }}" if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? Asking, because an error "ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'sheepposu'" usually appears when you are trying to filter something or POST a form and passing some params, not just in a template. {{question.author}} should work fine in your case and just return id of author object. I want to find a place where you are passing username 'sheepposu' as it's said in an error text you posted above.

Comment: If you will delete the slicing of a queryset (Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10]), will an error remains ?

Comment: I changed it to "Question.objects.all()" because otherwise there's no way of testing it. The error still persists.

Comment: So I was trying migrations, then I noticed an error, so I deleted the question, then when I tried to remake the question I get an error which I will post over the current error up there. This I assume is the root of the problem.

Comment: You mean you deleted the Question model or the object?

Comment: I deleted the question object, not the model. Then I made a new question under the admin page or rather attempted to.

Comment: Okay, it clearly seems to be a migration problem right now. Can you recreate your DB and rerun all the migrations? Or, possibly the renaming of a question could help. Or you could set db_table in model meta options if you don't want to recreate everything. Have you made any changes in the User model or settings that could cause this error?

Comment: Ok, I deleted all the migrations, the database, then re-migrated, and it's working again, I'll try to add the author later after everything seems to be working fine

Comment: It now works, I just had to reset the database and all the migrations except for the __init__.py thx for helping

Comment: Nice ^_^ I will update an answer then )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is considered not to use `User` model directly. Instead, you should reference the user model using `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`

When you define a foreign key or many-to-many relations to the user model, you should specify the custom model using the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

**Updated**

As we found out in the comments below the post itself, the core problem was in the models' relationship and the solution that helped was:

> delete all the migrations, the database, then re-migrate everything.

Pretty radical, but as it seems, something crashed due to the work with the standard User model, which happens sometimes in Django and the solution above, if it is possible, almost every time helps solving problems like that ^_^